# How to link a Google Form to a Google Sheet using Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms, pydrive

Here's my setup and what I want to accomplish:

- I currently have a Google Form set up for users to submit information, which is then logged in a Google Sheet.
- I then, use PyDrive to save the contents of the Google Sheet as a csv.
- Pandas then reads that csv, and deletes data within the csv based on certain criteria.
- After that, I use PyDrive to re-upload the "fixed" csv to Google sheets, saving over the old one.

Here's the problem:

whenever I do this, it terminates the link between the Google Sheet and Google Form. Is there some way I can preserve this link or re-link the Form and the Sheet?

Here is the snippet of code I have been playing with:

```
submissions_data = drive.CreateFile({'id': ext['SUBMISSIONS_ID']})
submissions_data.GetContentFile("data.csv", mimetype = "text/csv")
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.drop([0],inplace=True)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
submissions_data.SetContentFile("data.csv")`
```

Preferably, I would like to find a way to do this using PyDrive, but anything will work at this point. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: are you creating a new file rather than updating the existing file?

Comment: @DaImTo I'm sure I am, but I think that is the closest I can get to updating a file according to [PyDrive's documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#upload-and-update-file-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Google Drive API with *oauth2client* and *gspread* to update the existing spreadsheet directly.

1. Go to the [Google APIs Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/). Create a new project. Click Enable
   API.
2. Enable the [Google Drive API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com). Create credentials
   for a Web Server to access Application Data.
3. Name the service account and grant it a Project Role of Editor.
4. Download the JSON file.
5. Copy the JSON file to your code directory and rename it to
   client_secret.json
6. Find the  client_email inside client_secret.json. Back in your spreadsheet, click the Share button in the top right, and paste the client email into the People field to give it edit rights. Hit Send.

```
pip install gspread oauth2client
```

```
#spreadsheet.py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds =   ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Copy of Legislators 2017").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

You can write to the spreadsheet by changing a specific cell:

```
sheet.update_cell(1, 1, "I just wrote to a spreadsheet using Python!")
```

Or you can insert a row in the spreadsheet:

```
row = ["I'm","inserting","a","row","into","a,","Spreadsheet","with","Python"]
index = 1
sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

Check the [gspread API reference](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the full details on these functions along with a few dozen others.